# Python labelimg expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType

Tags: python, labelimg

I was trying to install `labelImg`. But when I try to change `pascalVoc` to `YOLO`, `labelImg` crashes. The traceback is as follows:

[image]

Comment: Post your code and results as text, not an image. Just from the title, I would suggest checking the return value of a function to make sure it returned a value, not `None`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.